# Qual a origem de "Mais vale um pobre bem governado do que um rico desmazelado." desmazelado é descuidado??

Tags: português-brasileiro, expressões, português-europeu, definição, frases

Qual a origem de "Mais vale um pobre bem governado do que um rico desmazelado." desmazelado é descuidado? ?

Comment: Sim. Basicamente, a expressão significa "mais vale ter pouco dinheiro e saber geri-lo, do que ter muito e o desperdiçar"

Comment: Será q pode usar o comentário como resposta ? Obr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente, a expressão significa "mais vale ter pouco dinheiro e saber geri-lo, do que ter muito e o desperdiçar". Não sei a origem exata desta expressão, mas uma expressão equivalente seria: "Mais quero asno que me leve que cavalo que me derrube".

A origem desta segunda expressão já é mais conhecida:

> Do programa “Lugares Comuns”, da autoria
>   de Mafalda Lopes da Costa, Antena 1, de 24 de janeiro de 2012:
>
> Passar de cavalo para burro corresponde a ficar em pior situação, descer de categoria ou posto, passar de um cargo importante
>   para outro que lhe é inferior, descer de posição social, em suma, ser
>   rebaixado, ficar pior.
>   Segundo o filólogo brasileiro Aurélio Buarque de Holanda, a expressão nasceu por analogia com uma antiga prática de sanção
>   militar. Antigamente, no exército a cavalo, o sargento que perdia as
>   divisas, por exemplo, por má conduta, e passava par acabo ou soldado
>   raso perdia também o cavalo e era-lhe dado a montar uma mula ou mesmo
>   um burro.